# Android Auto and Cluster or Dashboard App

Tags: android, android-auto

I want to develop an application which is a dashboard of car with android. The CANbus will be used as a communication protocol, I guess that I must use the android auto version but all examples about it shows that it's a multimedia screen for cars. Can I develop a dashboard which has gauges provides to display speedometer, odometer so forth with android auto?

Answer (score 0):

Android Auto takes care of rendering views to the screen when using the [Public SDK](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/), and only provides support for media or messaging apps with the provided templates. When using the SDK for Auto, there isn’t any availability to actually draw custom elements to the screen that is projected to the Head Unit.

Comment: So, I must use android OS not auto?

Comment: You'll need to use the Android Auto Public SDK to have an app that shows on the head unit. Its just that the SDK only allows apps that support either media or messaging, and nothing that can be drawn to the screen such as a custom dashboard with odometers etc..